# Different styling for multiple h6 headings on one page

Tags: html, css

What would be the proper way to style multiple h6 headings differently on one page?
I was thinking of the following:

css:

```
.content{ width:660px; overflow:hidden; }

.content h6{ margin:25px 20px 0px 35px;
             font-size:32px;
             padding-bottom:5px;
             font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
 }

.blue {
     color:#60817a;
     border-bottom:2px solid #99bcb4;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #99BCB4;
 }

.black {
         color:#000000;
         border-bottom:2px solid #333333;
         text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333333;
     }
```

html:

```
<div class="content">
<h6 class="blue">Subtitle</h6>

 <div class="content">
 <h6 class="black">Subtitle</h6>
```

Comment: Looks like it would work to me.  What do you think are the issues?

Comment: Whatever works for you - but having different heading styles on the same webpage is frowned upon - for example, by http://csslint.net/.

Comment: @ Brian & ngen Thx, I didn't think it was proper to add an extra class to a heading.

Comment: It's probably more proper to not use a header at all, just a class for what you want.

Comment: @ egasismus Tnx for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. For a selector to take precedence over another selector, you need to consider its [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Your `.blue` selector will not be as specific as your `.content h6` selector, based on the rules outlined in that link (try adding `color: red` to the `content h6` selector; other rules will take precedence like this). Try making the second selector `.content .blue` instead.
2. `blue` is a bad name for a class; for classes and IDs to be semantic, you should choose a name that describes what it is, rather than what it looks like (i.e. looks a bit daft when you change your CSS and decide that it should be red instead).